# How to increase/decrease brightnes using Fn+Home/End key in ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo T520

Tags: 12.04

i got a bright screen which is killing my eyes and can't even control the brightness using FN+home/end key. Any one got any idea how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: We will need more information about your hardware..as in which system you are using etc. please include them in your question

Answer (score 0):

open system settings in your sidebar or from power key on top of your screen and in its personal part open brightness and lock. Then set your desired brightness.